# Rename the name of uploaded file

Tags: php, file

Can someone help me fix my code so that it rename the files which is being uploaded? I wish to rename is with timestamp but without losing its extension.

My current code below is uploading files no doubt but i am clueless how to get the names renamed.

here is my code

```
<?php
    $path = 'uploads/resume/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path);
?>
```

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work? I cannot see any code that renames the file with any timestamp

Comment: @NicoHaase I wish to rename the file to timestamp